# Net::SCP password prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, net-ssh

Net::SCP requires password even though it is provided. Host machine has authorized_keys.pub and id_rsa.pub from user's machine. 
User has id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
I also have tried to enter the ssh_key which was the preferred way of doing so from the start, still requires a pass.
The gist with the code is located at: https://gist.github.com/maimutza/fd45c16c220410a94420

Comment: I am not too familiar with Net::SCP however I use SSH quite a bit. Have you tried SSH'ing into the machine manually first to ensure that it is not an issue with your keys or permissions?

Comment: @pyRabbit: thank you for your answer. I can SSH manually, I can accomplish the code in the gist if I provide the password again, but it is not what I seek.

Comment: Wait, is your authorized_keys file called 'authorized_keys.pub' or is that a typo?

Comment: it is authorized_keys.pub

Comment: I am pretty sure it needs to be just authorized_keys (without the .pub)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough. Please post your comment as a response so I can accept it.

Comment: No problem :) glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect name for your authorized_keys file.

Change authorized_keys.pub to authorized_keys